# How to say "Alexander I" in German, French, Italian, Portuguese, Spanish?

Tags: german, spanish, french, portuguese

What are the proper ways to say something like "Alexander I" in German, French, Italian, Portuguese, Spanish? In English, you say "Alexander the First". Do you say something like "Alexandre le Premier" in French? Does the the first/second/etc. part agree with the sex of the person? Apparently, they use "Elizabeth Ire" in French, but I'm not sure about the other languages. I'm also not sure where to find references on this or even how to Google this.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the list of [on-topic](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions for this site.  This question falls outside the purview of this site, as it is about pronunciation rules in specific languages. You would be better off asking on the [language-specific sites](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/a/439/13) for the languages that interest you.

Answer (score 4):

In Romance languages, adjectives and nouns agree in number and gender, so there are different versions for kings and queens:

- Catalan: Alexandre primer, Elisabet primera.
- Spanish: Alejandro primero, Isabel primera.
- Italian: Alessandro Primo, Elisabetta Prima ([note capitalization of ordinal numbers in this context in Italian](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-count-in-italian-4039800)).
- French: Alexandre premier, but beyond the first, cardinal numbers are used instead of ordinal numbers ([Henri quatre](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/un-deux-trois-les-nombres-cardinaux-ou-les-adjectifs-numeraux-cardinaux.html)).
- Portuguese: Alexandre Primeiro ([reference](https://books.google.es/books?id=Gm8yS1ZKJ5gC&lpg=PA93&ots=oNzwD8WrEW&dq=ordinal%20numbers%20portuguese%20kings&hl=ca&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q=ordinal%20numbers%20portuguese%20kings&f=false), although I found contradictory sources about capitalization).

Non-Romance languages:

- German: Alexander der Erste, Elisabeth die Erste.

Disclaimer: except for Catalan and Spanish, the answers are based on research from grammar books and online sources, and therefore I might have mis-interpreted. Comments and corrections are welcome.

Comment: German is correct, source: I'm a native speaker.